# Ensuring only one thread is in a class

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a DAO class which has multiple methods which update DB tables. These methods are called in many different places throughout the codebase, in many different orders.

```
public class Dao {
  public synchronized updateA()
  public synchronized updateB()
  public synchronized updateC()
  public synchronized getA()
  public synchronized getB()
  public synchronized getC()
}
```

I'm having an issue where Class1 wants to call `getA()`, `getB()`, and `getC()` in sequence. The three tables A, B, and C are related, so I need to get their state synchronized at one point in time.

However, after Class1 calls `getA()` and before it calls `getB()`, Class2 on another thread jumps in and calls `updateB()`, which breaks things.

Is it possible to lock the entire DAO class while any thread is in there, and only unlock it when it's finished?

I've tried putting a static ReentrantLock in the DAO class and locking it from Class1, but I'm not sure how to go from there.

I've gotten as far as the following:

```
public class Class1 {
  public void check() {
    dao.daoLock.lock();
    dao.getA();
    dao.getB();
    dao.getC();
    dao.daoLock.unlock();
  }
}

public class Dao {
  public static final daoLock = new ReentrantLock();
  public synchronized updateA() {
    daoLock.lock();
    // Do stuff...
  }
  public synchronized updateB() {
    daoLock.lock();
    // Do stuff...
  }
  public synchronized updateC() {
    daoLock.lock();
    // Do stuff...
  }
  public synchronized getA() {
    daoLock.lock();
    // Do stuff...
  }
  public synchronized getB() {
    daoLock.lock();
    // Do stuff...
  }
  public synchronized getC() {
    daoLock.lock();
    // Do stuff...
  }
}
```

I'm unsure about the location of the unlock. If I put it in each the DAO class methods it's going to let other threads in isn't it?

Is there a better solution here?

Comment: Maybe add a `synchronized updateAandB()` method that updates A and B atomically? Or change your policy so that the synchronization is done at the calling site (probably on the class instance itself)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to synchronise access to the database on the client side, which is fundamentally the wrong place to do it. What if another client did a write in the meantime?

It's better to leave this kind of synchronisation to the database itself, using *transactions* ([MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-transactions.html)).

Even if you don't have multiple clients and never will, using transactions is a better solution. Otherwise, all your threads will be blocked on each other even if they are just doing reads, which in principle can happen concurrently just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the good answer from Thomas, there is another aspect here worth looking at: *interfaces* should be written in a way that makes it easy to do the right thing; and hard to do the wrong thing.

Meaning: if some operation requires you to call a(), b(), c() in sequence, and in a "overall locked manner", then: instead of having a, b, c on your interface, you provide exactly **one** method abc() ... that acquires the lock, calls a,b,c and releases the lock.

So, you should step back and have a look at the interface of your class from a [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) perspective; or more specific - considering it from the "single responsibility principle" side of things.

In other words: having **one** class that provides a lot of completely "disjunct" methods; where some of them even need to be "used together, in a very specific manner" that is a clear design smell; so another indication that you better step back and review this design.